# Conditional formatting based on list filtering

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

**History**: I have created a excel dashboard displaying categories and their measures. I have given a list option filtering to display either growth or rank. I have used Green to red conditional formatting to display the high to low performance.

**Problem**: When I filter on growth % it shows proper conditional formatting i.e. higher the growth greener the cell and vice versa. But this won't be case in Rank. Lower the rank greener should be the cell is the ideal way to display top performer. This should be the ideal solution. But I am unable to find a way to do that.

**Possible solution where help is needed**: Clubbing conditional formatting with **'if'** formula or similar to change conditional formatting based on filter value. Can we have two conditional formatting rules based on certain cell condition?

Comment: You can have as many conditional formatting rules as you want on a cell based on whatever formula you use. Unless I misunderstand you, I don't see the problem here.

Comment: You could also return a "reversed rank" where top performer are ranked last. This would allow you to use the same rule.

Comment: It's very interesting problem. I am not sure if you can solve this using pure Excel. With VBA the simplest solution may be delete and add proper conditional formatting when you change growth/rank cell (Worksheet Change event), but this may slow down the worksheet a bit

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can click Conditional Formatting > New Rule... several times, and each time specify a different condition and different formatting.
To highlight cells according to multiple conditions being met, you can use the IF and AND Functions within a conditional formatting rule.

1- Select the range you want to apply formatting to.
2- In the Ribbon, select **Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.**
3- Select Use a formula to determine which cells to format, and enter the following formula:
=IF(AND(B4>5, B4<10),TRUE,FALSE)

4- Click on the Format button.
5- Set a format. For example, an orange fill color.
6- Click OK, then OK again to return to the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager.
7- Click Apply to apply the formatting to your selected range and then click Close.
.
.
.
The process to highlight cells based on the value contained in that cell in Google Sheets is similar to the process in Excel.

1- Highlight the cells you wish to format, and then click on Format > Conditional Formatting.
2- The Apply to Range section will already be filled in.
3- From the Format Rules section, select Custom Formula.
4- Select the fill style for the cells that meet the criteria.
5- Click Done to apply the rule.